# How can I solve this system please?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, control-systems, heat-equation

I need to solve the following impulsive heat equation:

$$
    \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \partial_{t} \psi(x,t)-\partial_{xx} \psi(x,t)=0, & (x,t)\in (0,1) \times((0, 2) \backslash\{1\}) \\
    \psi(0,t)= \psi(1,t)=0, & t \in  (0, 2) \\
    \psi(x, 0)= x (1-x), & x \in (0,1) \\
    \psi(x, 1)=\psi\left(x, 1^{-}\right)+4, & x \in (0,1)
    \end{array}\right.
    $$

$1^{-}$  denotes the limit to the left!

This is the code I tried in Mathematica, but it's not giving the results

```
                                                                  \
                               (*Numerical solution*)
homogene = {D[g[x, t], {t, 1}] - D[g[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0};
(*Initial conditions*)
ice = {g[x, 0] == x*(1 - x)};
(*Dirichlet boundary conditions*)
bce = {g[0, t] == 0, g[1, t] == 0};
(*solution*)
sol11 = (NDSolve[{homogene, ice, bce}, g, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    MaxStepSize -> 0.1]) /. K -> L
                        (*second part*)
ic3 = {g[x, 1] == (g[x, 1] /. First[sol11]) +  4 * HeavisidePi[x-1/2]}
sol33 = NDSolve[{homogene, ic3, bce}, g, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 1, 2}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 0.1]
```

Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2295039

Comment: You have asked this question before, why did you not just edit that post you had already made?

Comment: Also asked here https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2295039 and the x=1 advice there was ignored.

Comment: @walidfssm Function $\psi(x,1^{+})=\psi(x,1^{-})+4$ is not satisfies to the `bc` . Is this not really 4, but `4 HeavisidePi[x-1/2]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev:  `HeavisidePi[x-1/2]` isn't quite what you would want, because it doesn't evaluate to a numerical value at $x = 0$ or $x = 1$.  A custom-built `Piecewise` would be better.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish this is simply to integrate over $t \in [0,1]$, "stop the clock", add 4 to $\psi$ at that time, and then integrate over $t \in [0,2]$:

```
homogen = {D[f[x, t], {t, 1}] - D[f[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0};
(*Initial conditions*)
ic1 = {f[x, 0] == x*(1 - x)};
(*Dirichlet boundary conditions*)
bc = {f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0};
(*solution*)
sol1 = (DSolve[{homogen, ic1, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]) /. K -> L
```

[image]

```
ic2 = {f[x, 1] == (f[x, 1] /. First[sol1]) + 4}
sol2 = DSolve[{homogen, ic2, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

A few notes on what I've done here:

- I renamed the generated constants from `K` to `L` in the first step to avoid confusion in the final expression.  (I am unsure how to get Mathematica to do this on its own;  `GeneratedConstants` does not seem to have an effect on these dummy summation indices.)
- It should be possible to perform the integrals in this expression and express them as a sum over only one index rather than two.  However, I'm not sure how to get Mathematica to do this.  `Activate` doesn't do it, unfortunately.

---

**EDIT:** My code above also returns a solution if you replace `DSolve` with `NDSolve`.  It does throw an warning message (not an error, strictly speaking) about how your initial conditions are inconsistent with your boundary conditions;  this is because of the disagreement between the conditions of $\psi(0,t) = \psi(1,t) = 0$ and $\psi(x,1_-) = \psi(x, 1_+) + 4$ when $x = 0$ & $t = 1$.  This said, it still returns a solution that looks right.

If you really want to avoid this warning message, you could replace the `4` with a `Piecewise` function as follows:

```
ic2 = {f[x, 1] == (f[x, 1] /. First[sol1]) + 
    Piecewise[{{0, x == 0}, {0, x == 1}}, 4]}
```

This `Piecewise` function evaluates to 0 on the boundaries and 4 everywhere else.  This means it's consistent with the boundary conditions, and so it returns a solution with no warning messages.

Finally, note that the replacement `K -> L` is not necessary in the code for the numerical solution, though it doesn't do any harm either.

Comment: Michael Seifert Thank you so much for your help, I tried the same code  with NDsolve, But I get one error in the second system (when {t,1,2})                                                                sol1 = (NDSolve[{homogen, ic1, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 0.1]) /. K -> L  and  sol2 = NDSolve[{homogen, ic2, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 1, 2}, 
 MaxStepSize -> 0.1]                                                                                                                             Result: NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.

Comment: @walidfssm: That's a problem with your problem statement, not with your code;  see Alex Trounev's comment on your question.  If $\psi(0,t) = 0$ for all $t$, this is inconsistent with $\psi(x,1_+) = \psi(x,1_-) + 4$ when $x = 0$.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert thank you, you make it clear, I tried to correct that by putting                                  ic2 = {f[x, 1] == (f[x, 1] /. First[sol1]) + 
    4 * Piecewise[{{0, x == 0}, {0, x == 1}}, {x}]}
sol2 = NDSolve[{homogen, ic2, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 1, 2}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 0.1]                                                                                                                         But it's not working for me, Can you please help me to find the error again !!

Comment: @walidfssm:  Did you try Alex Trounev's suggestion of `HeavisidePi` in the comments on your question?  If you did and it didn't work, please edit your original question to include the current version of your code.

Comment: Yeh I tried Alex Trounev's suggestion of HeavisidePi and it doesn't work. And I just edit my original question to include the current version of my code                                   Thank you

Comment: @walidfssm:  See my edited answer.

Comment: @ Michael Seifert Thank you so much, it's working with no error                                                                      One other question please: I tried to plot the solution using the Plot function, it works but it looks strange (not like expected), please take a look at this code and tell me what do you think:  Show[{Table[
   Plot[g[x, t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> None, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red], {x, 0, 1}], 
  Table[Plot[g[x, t] /. sol33, {t, 1, 2}, Exclusions -> None, 
    PlotRange -> All], {x, 0, 1}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126764/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-walid-fssm).

Comment: I think `NDSolve` and `DSolve` return [a weak solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution) of the probem.